# How to eliminate Undefined Behavior in this code

Tags: vb.net

```
Function ChewQuery(QueryList As String)
    'This function takes in a string and partitions it into a weight tree
    Dim ElementList() As String
    ElementList = QueryList.Split(";")
    Dim LoadedWeight(ElementList.Length) As WeightElement
    For x = 0 To ElementList.Length - 1
        'Using this method, in which the front portion of the query is repeatedly removed, allows for a simpler query structure, so that we don't need to partition between the pointers and values
        LoadedWeight(x).LowPointer = Int(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        LoadedWeight(x).HighPointer = Int(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        LoadedWeight(x).TraitPointer = Int(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        LoadedWeight(x).Num = Int(BiteQuery(ElementList(x)))
        ChewQueryValues(ElementList(x), LoadedWeight(x))
    Next
    Return LoadedWeight
End Function
Function BiteQuery(ByRef QueryList As String)
    Dim Marker As Integer
    Dim Bite As String
    'This function partitions the input string around the first comma
    'It returns the section before the comma, and stores the section behind the comma as the new value for the string
    Try
        Marker = InStr(QueryList, ",")
        Bite = Left(QueryList, Marker - 1)
        Marker = Len(QueryList) - Marker
        QueryList = Right(QueryList, Marker)
    Catch
        'This is used in the case that a list without a comma is input
        Bite = QueryList
        QueryList = ""
    End Try
    Return Bite
End Function
Sub ChewQueryValues(ByRef QueryList As String, ByRef LoadedWeight As WeightElement)
    LoadedWeight.Values = {}
    While Len(QueryList) > 0
        'This While loop is so that an arbitrary number of values can be inserted
        'Because BiteQuery takes in functions by reference, each loop reduces the length of the string until it is empty
        ReDim Preserve LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length + 1)
        LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length - 1).TraitName = BiteQuery(QueryList)
        LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length - 1).TraitNum = Int(BiteQuery(QueryList))
        LoadedWeight.Values(LoadedWeight.Values.Length - 1).WeightValue = CDec(BiteQuery(QueryList))
    End While
End Sub
```

This set of functions is exhibiting some sort of undefined/random behavior when run in the following case:

```
FullToken = Strings.Right(Strings.Left(Query, 10), 5) 'This set of functions will extract the 5 rightmost characters of the 10 leftmost characters. This is equivalent to the 5th to 10th characters, which is where the token is stored
QueryText = Strings.Right(Query, Len(Query) - 11)
ReDim Preserve Weight(Weight.Length + 1)
Weight(Weight.Length - 1).Token = FullToken 'This puts the token in the list
Weight(Weight.Length - 1).Weight = ChewQuery(QueryText) 'This puts the weight in the list
WeightList.Text += vbCrLf + FullToken 'This adds the token to the viewable label
```

This is causing other important parts of the program to fail, which is not desirable. How do I fix this code so that it performs identically on each run of the program?

Comment: Use the debugger. That's what it's there for. Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and then step through it line by line, examining the state of relevant variables and other expressions at each step. You will then be able to identify exactly where and how the code does not behave as you expect. If you still can't work out how to fix it, you can at least relay all that relevant information to us.

Comment: Start by turning on `Option Strict` and giving your functions return types.

Comment: The value of 'Query' used in the case provided would provide some substance for a walkthrough of the functions. Also how the Weight (structure?) is implemented with its Token and Weight fields/properties since .Weight must be an array of WeightElement items.